# Bulldog Edging Knife Useless

Tags: tools, tool-maintenance

I was all excited yesterday when I got home from work. I had received an email from Amazon saying my new [Bulldog Edging Knife](http://amzn.eu/4Gft9Zo) had been delivered.

I opened up the box, unwrapped the tool, and was so disappointed. These are like one of the most expensive edging knifes you can buy, yet here is its **"** sharp edge **"**.

[image: sharp edge]

It is like 2mm thick, very very dull. Does anyone have any experience with these tools? Aren't they supposed to be sharp? The one I borrowed from my neighbour was quite sharp.

Comment: I;'ve just googled 'bulldog edging knife' and it showed me a half moon edger on Amazon - what is that tool you've got there, exactly, can't see the rest of it?

Comment: added link to the one I bought

Comment: Its a half moon edger then... some are sharper than others, but if you've got a whetstone, that'll sharpen it up a bit, but they're not usually really, really sharp anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should not need to be even as sharp as a spade, because penetration is less (say 2 - 3 inches rather than nearer 12"). And used like a spade (forced down with a foot on top of the blade) even quite blunt should 'do the job'.

On the other hand, if there are stones or pebbles or roots to 'cut' through robustness is a good idea. I had one where the metal attaching the blade to the handle bent for not being as 'meaty' as I would have liked.

I'd probably take a grindstone to yours but not aim for the sharpness of a scalpel - just normal soil would take such an edge off very quickly.

Comment: Thanks, yep I've been reading on the sharpening angle, and apparently it should be around 30 degrees. Not sure how I would get that sort of angle though, and with what! I called some local shops, and they said they didn't sharpen garden tools :/

Comment: thanks @pnuts, I'll get that and an angle grinder (should come useful for other things around the house too)